# Can't connect to my Ubuntu server trough domain (Caddy)

Tags: http, ubuntu, flask, server, caddy

I have Ubuntu server on Lightsail with webapp. I am using Caddy as web server and i have flask app on it. When i connected to the server directly with ip i could see my web app. But when i tried connecting to the server with domain, it says it takes to long to respond. I contacted my domain provaider and he said to make my own DNS server (I am beginner and i dont know much about servers)

Caddy file:

```
    exploresrpska.com {
    reverse_proxy localhost:50100
}
```

**This is my activation process which worked wiht ip adress only**

1. `source env/bin/activate` - Activating Venv
2. `cd Turizam` - Changing directories
3. `caddy stop`
4. `sudo caddy start`- Properly starting caddy web server
5. `python run.py`

Dont really know what to do or try because am new to this and i was following tutorial. If you need more info i will expand on it.